# Homeomorphism of quotient spaces

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic spaces with homeomorphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$, is it true that for any subspace $A$ of $X$, $X/A$ and $Y/f(A)$ are homeomorphic? If so, how to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $g : X / A \to Y/f(A)$ which sends the equivalence class $[x]$ to the equivalence class $[f(x)]$.